# Android Studio Setup JDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in Android.  I created a few android hello world - apps, using Android Studio 1.2.2.

But now I see problems

[image]

This applies not only to new projects, and to all, even projects worked yesterday.

Setup is to specify the path to SDK and JDK.There  like it right.
[image]

Android Studio run on Windows 10.

My Enviroment Variables:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem could be that the android sdk is 32-bit while the JDK is 64-bit.

Comment: Thanx, I try 32-bit JDK, doesn't works :(

Comment: add the whole path including the bin folder in the Path in Environment Variables for both the JDK and the JRE
"C:\...jdk8\bin;C:\...jre8\bin"
See if that works.

Comment: Android Studio doesn't start with this Path = "C:\...jdk8\bin;C:\...jre8\bin". And JDK only including bin doesn't start too.